# redis-cli does not redirect requests to cluster mode enabled redis with in-transit enabled

Tags: redis

I have a AWS elasticache(cluster mode enabled)  with encryption-in-transit enabled and trying to use redis-cli with stunnel enabled.

I can connect to the cluster but redirection is not happening. The command to get a key value just hangs.

```
$ ./redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379  -a <password> -c

localhost:6379> ping
PONG
localhost:6379> get "test"
-> Redirected to slot [6918] located at abc-0002-001.abc.wxamam.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
^C
$
```